# ¿Que gema puedo utilizar a para validar usuarios en mi web?

Tags: ruby

¿cuáles gemas puedo utilizar para validar usuarios en mi sitio web? ¿o es posible con puro ruby?

Con php o jsp usaba javascript, pero en ruby no se si se pueda

Comment: http://www.peoplecancode.com/es/tutorials/how-to-manage-users-with-devise-ruby-on-rails



encontré esta pero la verdad nose?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la gema [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), agregala a tu Gemfile poniendo `gem 'devise'`

Answer (score 0):

Hola Sommer las gemas son exclusivamente de Ruby On Rails, framework de Ruby, porque quieres programar en Ruby nativo? Si es web lo que programas, deberas hacerlo en Rails

Comment: No  si claro uso el frame work rails ruby pero necesito válidar usuario y como soy novato en ruby ps y gracias por la gema

Comment: Claro tal como te recomienda Aldanux, Devise sera tu solucion, puedes ver su documentacion directamente aqui: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: @HectorHernandez estas equivocado, las gemas son de ruby.

Answer (score 0):

La más utilizada claro está es Devise, la puedes acompañar con Cancan por si tendrás algunos Roles/Privilegios para cierto tipos de usuarios, si tu app es un poco más compleja te aconsejo utilizar estas tres:

Devise: [Documentación](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Cancan: [Documencación](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Rolify: https: //github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify  (No me deja insertar mas de dos vinculos el stack, Sorry).

Si solo necesitas algún Login, utiliza Devise.

Saludos.